# Finite direct sum of subspaces and equality

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $E_1, \dots, E_r, F_1, \dots, F_r$ be subspaces of the vector space V such that
$$ \bigoplus^{r}_{i=1}{E_i} = \bigoplus^{r}_{i=1}{F_i} $$
and $\forall i \in \{1,\dots, r\}, E_i \subset F_i$. Show that $E_i = F_i$.

I know we only need to show that $F_i \subset E_i$, thus that every vectors of $F_i$ is also in $E_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each $F_i$ where $F_i \neq E_i$, pick $f_i \in F_i \setminus E_i$. Let $B$ be the collection of these $f_i$. Then $\mathrm{span}(B)$ is a non-trivial subspace of $\bigoplus_i F_i$ that does not intersect $\bigoplus_i E_i$, a contradiction.